# Make several circles editable on google map when click on them and add listener

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In an angular application, I create circles on a google map using the following loop:

```
for (this.ind in circles) {
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: circles[this.ind].center,
    radius: circles[this.ind].radius,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    draggable: true,
    map: map
  });

}
```

When the circles are created I want to click on each one and make it editable so in include the following inside the loop (before the closing curly bracket):

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'click', (event) => {
    console.log("click");
    circle.setEditable(true);
  });
```

My problem is the whenever I click on a circle, only the last one is changed to editable.
My goal is to click on each circle, make it editable and then apply listeners to `center_changed` and `radius_changed` events.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by putting every new shape into an array and the I catch the click event by looping through the array:

```
let a = 0;
let indx;
let shapes = [];

for (indx in circles) {
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    circleID: a,
    center: circles[indx].center,
    radius: circles[indx].radius,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    draggable: true,
    // editable: true,
    map: map
  });

  a++;
  shapes.push(circle);
}

for (let i in shapes) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(shapes[i], 'click', (event) => {
    console.log(shapes[i].circleID)
  }
}
```

So when i want to add a addListener on an event, I put it inside the `for (let i in shapes)` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` inside the click listener function, it is a reference to the circle that was clicked.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'click', (event) => {
  console.log("click");
  this.setEditable(true);
});
```